# Composing an regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

This is regarding composing an regular expression to satisfy the given conditions.

The conditions are:

1. I wanted to return true/false if a particular word is present in the paragraph.
2. The word can be anywhere (in the beginning, middle, or end)
3. It should return only for whole words with an exception. The word can precede (or) follow by only one special character such as ,.;()[]{} etc
4. Also it is case insensitive search.

In the below code I am searching for a word Positive. I have hardcoded the string in the regex. Ideally in this case the output should be false, but it is returning true.
So I am not sure how to do this.

```
String inputStr = "ssdf Positiveasd asd sdfewrewr asd";  
inputStr = inputStr.toUpperCase();  

String patternStr = "[^a-z]*[\\s]?[^\\d\\w]?[POSITIVE\b]+[^a-z]*";  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);  

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
boolean matchFound = matcher.matches();  

System.out.println(matchFound);
```

Comment: Note that you make an expression case insensitive by providing the correpsonding flag or adding `(?i)` at the beginning. This way you don't have to convert the input to upper/lower case.

Comment: Note that `[POSITIVE]` does not match `"POSITIVE"` but one of: `"P"`, `"O"`, `"S"`, `"I"`, `"T"`, `"V"` or `"E"`. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Please try to give your question a specific title - there are dozens of questions called "Java Regular Expression" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that `\b` means "backspace character" (which obviously isn't present in the string you're trying to match).

You want `\\b` (which the regex engine receives after string processing is done as `\b` (word boundary)). Don't forget that you need to escape backslashes in a Java string.

I would have constructed the regex much differently, though. However, I don't understand what you mean by your requirement no. 3. Could you provide a few examples to illustrate this?

Answer (score 1):

```
(\bPOSITIVE\b)
```

shall do the trick (says my cool regex debugger).  Square brackets define character class,  and round brackets pattern ( do not forget to double \ in java string literal )

Answer (score 1):

1. You need double escaping, so `\b` should become `\\b`
2. Don't put "POSITIVE" into square brackets, this creates a character class, means match any of the included characters.

   replace `[POSITIVE\b]+` with `POSITIVE\b`

When I understand your requirements correctly then you should only need `(?i)\\bpositive\\b`

The `(?i)` makes your `inputStr.toUpperCase()` unnecessary, because it makes the match case independent. The `\\b` is a word boundary means it is true if there is no word character before and no word character behind your word "positive".

**Test Code**

```
String s1 = "ssdf Positiveasd asd sdfewrewr asd";
String s2 = "ssdf Positive asd asd sdfewrewr asd";
String s3 = "ssdf poSiTive asd sdfewrewr asd";
String s4 = "ssdf FooPositive asd sdfewrewr asd";

String[] s = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
String regex = "(?i)\\bpositive\\b";

for(String a : s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
    
    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Success");
    else
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Failure");
}
```

**Output**

> ssdf Positiveasd asd sdfewrewr asd ==> Failure
> ssdf Positive asd asd sdfewrewr asd ==> Success
> ssdf poSiTive asd sdfewrewr asd ==> Success
> ssdf FooPositive asd sdfewrewr asd ==> Failure

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, you want to match things like

```
Positive; blah
Positive blah
blah Positive blah
```

But not things like your example string or

```
Positive;; blah
;Positive
```

Is that right? If so, I feel like you're overcomplicating things a bit with your expression...

How about something like this?

```
String patternStr = "[^\\s]+POSITIVE[\\b]?[$\\s]*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
```

Also, you'd probably want to make sure that your definition of "special character" is the same as what's meant by the \b word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the word boundary `\b` and see if it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to do something like:

```
public boolean doesInputContainWord(String inputStr, String word) {
    inputStr = inputStr.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", " ");
    word = " " + word.toLowerCase() + " ";
    return inputStr.contains(word);
}
```

This replaces every character in the input string that is not a letter with a space, and then checks to see if the transform text contains `word`.  Note that that is `<space> + <word> + <space>`.

Or, if you really want to use a regex to do the matching, then I would suggest removing the `[]` around "POSITIVE", as well as the `\b` and the `+` that comes after.  The brackets are defining a character class, which is not what you want in this case.  You want to look for the literal text "POSITIVE".  The `[POSITIVE]+` would match things like "OOST" and "VIVE" and pretty much any string that contains one or more letters from the word "Positive".

Answer (score -1):

You could also use

```
if(inputStr.indexOf("Positive") > 0){
   //Word is found
}
```

Comment: this would ignore word boundaries